# summing two more column

Tags: sql

I have two tables `readysale` and `ordersale`. I want to get the sum of two table. the column of table like 
`t1=pid,branch,quantity` 
and 
`t2=pid,branch,quantity`.I need the List of all the branch in branch column and show the sum quantity of `readysale,ordersale`. 
Some branch they did not do the sales either ready or order but it should show in the list by 0 .

Comment: Please try to explain a bit better.

Comment: Please take some time to show sample tables and data if you want people to spend time on your question

Answer (score 1):

This will get the total quantity from both tables unioned together grouped by branch:

```
select sales.branch, sum(sales.quantity) as quantity
from (
    select branch, quantity
    from readysale
    union
    select branch, quantity
    from ordersale
) as sales
group by sales.branch
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(u.quantity) as total, u.branch 
from (
    select quantity, branch 
    from readysale
    union
    select quantity, branch 
    from ordersale
    ) as u
group by u.branch
```

EDIT :

Then

```
select u.itemcode, u.branch, sum(u.ordersaleqty), sum(u.readysaleqty)
from (
        select itemcode, branch, 0 as ordersalqty, quantity as readysaleqty 
        from readysale
        union
        select itemcode, branch, quantity as ordersalqty, 0 as readysaleqty  
        from ordersale
        ) as u
group by u.itemcode, u.branch
```

or use a full outer join

```
  select 
    coalesce(r.itemcode, o.itemcode), 
    coalesce(r.branch, o.branch),
    sum (r.quantity) as readysaleqty,
    sum (o.quantity) as ordersaleqty
  from readysale r
  full outer join ordersale o on o.branche = r.branch
  group by coalesce(r.itemcode, o.itemcode), coalesce(r.branch, o.branch);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I am looking for the a list like itemcode,brach,readysaleqty,ordersalequantity